# Is using `git checkout --theirs <filename>` a legitimate way of resolving a merge conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am updating from `master` and got a merge error with a file that I am not supposed to modified (I must have done so by accident).

Rather than trying to figure out the merge issues in the code, can I just tell git to use 'their' copy? Can I just use `git checkout --theirs` without any consequences?

If not, what would be the correct way of going about this?

Comment: Well, it’ll do what it says, but I suggest you make sure the changes you weren’t aware of making weren’t important with `git diff master...HEAD path/to/file`. If the conflict is short, having `merge.conflictstyle` set to `diff3` will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in fact, `git checkout --theirs -- path` to replace the work-tree version of the file (named *path*) with their version.  The `--` part is required only if the *`path`* resembles a `git checkout` option, e.g., if the file is named `--ours` or `--force` or something silly like that.  (It's good to get into the habit of using it, though, just in case.  Someday you'll stumble over a file named `-rf` and the `-- -rf` habit will prevent you from running `rm -rf`... :-) )

Due to Git letting the implementation show through, this *will not* mark the file as resolved, though.  You must separately `git add` the path to mark it as resolved.  This is because when the file is in conflicted state, all three versions—base, `--ours`, and `--theirs`—are stored in the three "conflicting versions" slots for that index entry.  To mark a file as resolved you must get Git to clobber these three slots and write the file to the more normal slot-zero entry.  That's how Git knows which files are resolved, and which are not: via these special higher-numbered index slots.

Peculiarly, if you `git checkout MERGE_HEAD path`, that *will* mark the file as resolved.  This is because this form of `git checkout` first copies the file from the specified commit—`MERGE_HEAD`—into index slot zero, then from there to the work-tree.  That "copy to slot 0" step resolves the merge conflict.  But note that if you *renamed* the file, the *`path`* you need with `--theirs` and the *`path`* you need with `MERGE_HEAD` will be different!